# Nativescript angular - Passing element variable as a parameter in an event

Tags: angular2-nativescript

**app.component.html**

```
<ListView [items]="stocks">
<template let-item="item" let-i="index">
    <StackLayout>
        <Label #{{item.name+item.id}} [text]="item.name" (tap)="setValue(item.name+item.id)"</Label>
    </StackLayout>
</template>
```

The parameter passed in setValue() comes in as a string in my code instead of an object.
How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You're concatenating 2 values so I'd expect it to become a string indeed. Can you try this `setValue(item)` instead?